# create a select dropdown option with values and text according to the specified data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

so below is my snippet. What I want is to create a select dropdown option base from the data attribute (data-select-text and data-select-values) of the currently clicked button, so below is a working snippet except for getting the data-select-values which is the problem because i dont know how to loop it along with the data-select-text so that the result of each select option will have values and text base from the split values of the data-select-text and data-select-values attribute, any ideas, help, suggestions, recommendations?

NOTE: currently, I could only able to use the attribute data-select-text as a select options values and text.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click", "button", function(){
    if($(this).attr("data-input-type").toLowerCase() === "select"){
      var classList = $(this).attr('data-select-text').split(/\s+/);
      var field = '<select>';
      $.each(classList, function(index, item) {
         field += '<option value="' + item.replace(/%/g, ' ') + '">' + item.replace(/%/g, ' ') + '</option>';
      });
      field += '</select>'; 
    }
    $("body").append(field);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button data-input-type="select" data-select-text="select%1 select%2 select%3" data-select-values="1 2 3">Create a select dropdown option</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, if I understand correctly. This code does not take into account different text or value lengths. It expects that the text length of options created is always equal to the values length being used.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "button", function () {
        if ($(this).attr("data-input-type").toLowerCase() === "select") {
            var classList = $(this).attr('data-select-text').split(/\s+/);
            var valueList = $(this).attr('data-select-values').split(' ');
            var field = '<select>';
            $.each(classList, function (index, item) {
                field += '<option value="' + valueList[index] + '">' + item.replace(/%/g, ' ') + '</option>';
            });
            field += '</select>';
        }
        $("body").append(field);
    })
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/32qt0vn8/

Comment: great, just what im thinking about. works like charm! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array for the values, the same as so did for the text.

Make sure that the order in both `data-select-text` and `data-select-values` is the same. Then you can use the index in your `$.each` loop:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", "button", function(){
        var elem = $(this);
        if( elem.attr("data-input-type").toLowerCase() === "select" ){
            var classList = elem.data('select-text').split(/\s+/), 
                valueList = elem.data('select-values').split(/\s+/), 
                field = '<select>';
            $.each(classList, function(index, item) {
                field += '<option value="' + valueList[index].replace(/%/g, ' ') + '">' + item.replace(/%/g, ' ') + '</option>';
            });
            field += '</select>'; 
        }
        $("body").append(field);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-input-type="select" data-select-text="select%1 select%2 select%3" data-select-values="1 2 3">Create a select dropdown option</button>
```

The result will be:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">select 1</option>
  <option value="2">select 2</option>
  <option value="3">select 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: great, just what im thinking about. works like charm! thank you!